# Creating a SELECT statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I have some tables called cohort, type, stage, cohort_eval tracker. The cohort table is a list of teams or groups. The type table is a list of types of evaluations that can be assigned to a cohort. There are only 2 types in the type table. The stage table is a list of stages within a type (Let's assume there are  3 stages but more can be added). For example, Type 1 can have stage1, stage2, stage3...etc. The cohort_eval_tracker is a table the keeps track of the evaluations a cohort has been assigned to. A cohort can only be assigned a stage only after the previous stage has completed. For example, if type 1 stage 1 ended January 1st then a cohort can be assigned to take type 2 stage 2 on January 2nd. A cohort can be assigned both types at the same time. So if a cohort is assigned type 1 stage 1 they can also take type 2 stage 2 at the same time as long as type 2 stage 1 ends before type 2 stage 2 starts.

I want to create a SELECT statement that returns cohorts who can still be assigned evaluations up to the maximum stage. So if a cohort hasn't taken any evaluations I want them to be returned or if a cohort hasn't been assigned their last stage (for this example it is stage 3 but more can be added in the future) then I want that cohort to be returned. My attempt below isn't correct because it is returning cohort 1 even though they have completed all 3 stages in both type 1 and type 2.

```
SELECT 
    cohortID, cohortName 
FROM 
    dbo.cohort 
WHERE 
    cohortID NOT IN (SELECT cohortID 
                     FROM cohort_eval_tracker 
                     WHERE stageID = (SELECT MAX(stageID) FROM stage) 
                       AND endDate < GETDATE()) 
    OR 
    cohortID NOT IN (SELECT cohortID  
                     FROM cohort_eval_tracker 
                     WHERE stageID = 2 AND (typeID = 1 OR typeID = 2))
```

Cohort_eval_tracker:

```
╔══════════════╦══════════╦════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ cohortEvalID ║ cohortID ║ typeID ║ stageID ║ startDate ║  endDate  ║
╠══════════════╬══════════╬════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║            1 ║        1 ║      1 ║       1 ║ 1/10/2015 ║ 1/11/2015 ║
║            2 ║        1 ║      1 ║       2 ║ 1/12/2015 ║ 1/22/2015 ║
║            3 ║        1 ║      1 ║       3 ║ 1/30/2015 ║ 2/1/2015  ║
║            4 ║        1 ║      2 ║       1 ║ 1/2/2015  ║ 1/3/2015  ║
║            5 ║        1 ║      2 ║       2 ║ 1/4/2015  ║ 1/5/2015  ║
║            6 ║        1 ║      2 ║       3 ║ 1/6/2015  ║ 1/7/2015  ║
║            6 ║        2 ║      1 ║       2 ║ 3/10/2016 ║ 3/16/2016 ║
╚══════════════╩══════════╩════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Stage:

```
╔═════════╦═══════════╗
║ stageID ║ stageName ║
╠═════════╬═══════════╣
║       1 ║ stage1    ║
║       2 ║ stage2    ║
║       3 ║ stage3    ║
╚═════════╩═══════════╝
```

Cohort:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╗
║ cohortID ║ cohortName ║
╠══════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ cohort1    ║
║        2 ║ cohort2    ║
╚══════════╩════════════╝
```

Type:

```
╔════════╦══════════╗
║ typeID ║ typeName ║
╠════════╬══════════╣
║      1 ║ type1    ║
║      2 ║ type2    ║
╚════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your attempt? Error? wrong data returned? Can you post a sample expected output

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: So for this case it should only be **cohort2** that should be returned since they haven't completed all their stages in either type 1 or type 2.

Comment: _Note: I updated the end dates on cohort_eval_tracker table so that it has an end date that has already passed indicating that it is already complete_

Comment: @mediumM Probably `AND` operator instead of `OR` will fix your query.

Answer (score 0):

Only a single sub query and a correlated sub query is needed for your WHERE statement.

```
SELECT cohortID, cohortName 
FROM dbo.cohort 
WHERE cohortID NOT IN (SELECT cohortID 
                       FROM cohort_eval_tracker 
                       WHERE (stageID = (SELECT MAX(stageID) 
                                         FROM stage) 
                       AND endDate < GETDATE())
                       OR (stageID = 2 
                       AND (typeID = 1 OR typeID = 2)))
```

Or by joining the tables and using a correlated sub query to select the `MAX` stageID from stage.

```
SELECT c.cohortID, c.cohortName 
FROM dbo.cohort c
INNER JOIN cohort_eval_tracker cet ON c.cohortID = cet.cohortID
WHERE (cet.stageID = (SELECT MAX(stageID) FROM stage) AND cet.endDate < GETDATE())
OR (cet.stageID = 2 AND (cet.typeID = 1 OR cet.typeID = 2))
```

Comment: Not an answer. A statement without any explanation at all.